# Rails Memoization of Helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a helper method that does expensive calculations and returns a `Hash`, and this Hash is constant during my entire application lifespan (meaning it can only change after a re-deploy) and it also doesn't take any arguments.

For performance, I wish I could 'cache' the resulting `Hash`.

I **don't** want to use Rails cache for this, since I want to avoid the extra trip to memcached and I don't want the overhead of de-serializing the string into a hash.

My first idea was to assign the resulting hash to a Constant and calling `.freeze` on it. But the helper is an instance method, the constant lives on the class, and I had to do this ultra hacky solution:

```
module FooHelper

def expensive_calculation_method
  resulting_hash
end

EXPENSIVE_CALCULATION_CONSTANT = Class.new.extend(self).expensive_calculation_method.freeze
```

This is due to the helper method being an instance method, the helper being a Module (which leads to the fake Class extend so I can call the instance method) and I also must declare the constant AFTER the instance method (if I declare it right after `module FooHelper`, I get an `undefined method 'expensive_calculation_method'`.

The second idea was to use memoization, but at least for Rails Controllers memoization is the persistance of a variable over the lifecycle of a *single request*, so it's only valuable if you reuse a variable many times from within a **single request**, which is not my case, but at the same time Helpers are modules, not Classes to be instanciated, and by this point I don't know what to do.

How would I cache that Hash, or memoize it in a way that persists over requests?

Comment: Constants declared inside a module should be available in any context that module's used or imported with `include`. Do you want to take the hit at start-up time or on the first instance of it being used?

Comment: You're describing the exact use case of view caching here. Can you explain more why you don't want to use the Rails cache?

Comment: @DanielWestendorf - The resulting Hash has hundreds of keys and it will be used in an extremely critical piece of the application, so I want it to be as performant as possible. If I use memcached for example, the hash will be serialized and saved there as a String, and every time it will need to be parsed (deserialized) into a ruby Hash again, let alone the cost of memcached trip that I want to avoid. Remember: this is a FIXED Hash, it won't change unless after a deploy, so I don't see why I need to serialize a native ruby Hash into a string and save it to memcached.

Comment: @tadman I wish to take the hit at start-up time.

Comment: Slinging data like that back and forth from Memcached or Redis is pretty effortless. Throwing it in a constant should also work. It's not clear what your specific problem is here.

Comment: @tadman I wished to know if throwing it in a constant the way I did it was an acceptable solution, since I never saw it before as a 'best practice' or idiomatic Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

Per your comments, this will only change at application boot, so placing it in an initializer would do the trick.

```
# config/initializers/expensive_thing.rb
$EXENSIVE_THING_GLOBAL = expensive_calculation

# or
EXPENSIVE_THING_CONSTANT = expensive_calculation

# or

Rails.application.config.expensive_thing = expensive_calcualatioin
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cache the result of some painful operation at launch time:

```
module MyExpensiveOperation
  COMPUTED_RESULT = OtherModule.expensive_operation

  def self.cached
    COMPUTED_RESULT
  end
end
```

Just make sure that module's loaded somehow or it won't initiate. You can always force-`require` that module if necessary in `environment.rb` or as a `config/initializer` type file.

If you want to lazy load the basic principle is the same:

```
module MyExpensiveOperation
  def self.cached
    return @cached if (defined?(@cached))

    @cached = OtherModule.expensive_operation
  end
end
```

That will handle operations that, for whatever reason, return `nil` or `false`. It will run once, and once only, unless you have multiple threads triggering it at the same time. If that's the case there's ways of making your module concurrency aware with automatic locks.

Comment: In your first example, what is the difference between calling the constant directly (`MyExpensiveOperation::COMPUTED_RESULT`) vs calling the class method (`MyExpensiveOperation.cached`) ?

Comment: I tend to avoid sharing "internals" between classes or modules, it creates unnecessary interdependencies. By having a method like `cached` it means you can change how `COMPUTED_RESULT` is defined, what it contains, without necessarily breaking all the associated code. `cached` can be updated to maintain compatibility. A constant has no such ability to adapt, it either is the correct format or isn't.